# check string for invalid characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, validation, textbox

I have a textbox called `Comment` in a form. After the user enters their comment and click on the save button I want to search through this comment string for any invalid character such as full stops, commas, brackets etc. 
If the string contains any of these character then I want to throw an exception.

I know in javascript you can use `RegularExpressionValidator` and check the validation with `ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"` but how can you do it in the code behind?

Right now I just check if the comment has been left empty but how do I check if the comment contains anything other than numbers and letters?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComment.Text))
{
    throw new Exception("You must enter a comment");
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for Regex.Match? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There are Regex in C# as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes use Regex  itis the most suitable solution.

Comment: Why restrict users from using those characters in a comment?  It sounds to me like you might be inserting the comments into a database and want to eliminate characters which might cause a problem with the sql statement.  There may be better ways to achieve this.  Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. But it is easier to only allow numbers or letters instead of checking for any unwanted characters individually

Comment: If you use parameterized queries to submit to the database, then you don't need to restrict any characters at all.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yes I use that, but I noticed that if you copy and paste an apostrophe into the the textbox it changes into a single right quote which ruins the sql query.

Comment: If you use parameterized queries, that won't happen.  That will only happen if you use string concatenation when creating your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is same logic using `Regex`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Match match = regex.Match(txtComment.Text);
if (!match.Success)
{
    throw new Exception("You must enter a valid comment");
}
```

Comment: `if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtComment.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))` is a shorter implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
// Basic Regex pattern that only allows numbers, 
// lower & upper alpha, underscore and space
static public string pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z_ ]";

static public string Sanitize(string input, string pattern, string replace)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create a regular expression object
        Regex rx;
        rx = new Regex(pattern);
        // Use the replace function of Regex to sanitize the input string. 
        // Replace our matches with the replacement string, as the matching
        // characters will be the ones we don't want in the input string.
        return rx.Replace(input, replace);
    }
}
```